# How to check which instance is reserved in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reserved

We have 2 reserved c3.xlarge instance in our project but have total 3 launched c3.xlarge instance.

How to check which 2 instances are reserved out of 3. I checked details of all 3 instances, but nothing is mentioned.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Reserved or not reserved is just a billing convenience. There is no concept of a particular instance being reserved or not.

So for example if you have two instances and have purchased on reserved instance and one is 'on demand', you can delete either one of them, and one of them is still reserved.

Comment: Just to extend on this answer... Each hour, the AWS billing system looks for Amazon EC2 instances that match purchased Reserved Instances. If it finds a match (based on Instance Type, Operating System and Availability Zone), one instance is not billed for that hour (per Reserved Instance owned). So, think of it more as a discount-granting system rather than a specific 'machine' being a reserved instance.

Answer (score 10):

To check your reserved instances:

1. login to your aws console.
2. Go to EC2 management page.
3. Expand Instances
4. Click on Reserved Instances

Here you can see all your available reserved instances if available, else "You do not have any Reserved Instances."  is displayed.